# Boolean value set to state toggles on it's own despite value is true

Tags: javascript, reactjs, boolean

I've created a component that contains a form used to validate youtube urls that has a state property that evaluates to true or false depending on whether or not the url (or any value) that's typed into the input field is a valid youtube url or not.

The function `validateUrl()` is the one responsible to return a boolean value depending on whether or not the URL is valid, the problem is despite this function returning true, the state of my component toggles between true and false every keystroke. [Click here to see a visual representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6N1Vo.jpg)

Here is the code:

```
const youtubeRegex = /^(https?\:\/\/)?(www\.)?(youtube\.com|youtu\.?be)\/.+$/gi;

class Converter extends Component {
  state = {
    id: null,
    url: "",
    urlValid: false
  };

  /**
   * Sets state whenever user types
   * @params {Object} event
   * @returns {void}
   */

  handleChange = event => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const valid = this.validateUrl(value);
    this.setState({
      id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100),
      url: value,
      urlValid: valid
    });
  };

  validateUrl = url => {
    return youtubeRegex.test(url);
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    ...logic for submission
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Converter">
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <input
            value={this.state.url}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
            autoComplete="off"
            type="text"
            placeholder="Add a link to convert..."
          />
          <p>{this.state.urlValid.toString() + " " + this.state.url}</p>
          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Don't mind the names of the variables and such, I've changed them a few times while trying to debug this. I have checked stackoverflow for similar situations and the most remotely close one I found was related to toggling a boolean state, my situation I believe is quite different.

Does this have to do with setState() being asynchronous? If so how would I go about fixing this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Issue is with the `test` method on the Regex. You need to remove the global flag(/g) from the regex.

> If the regex has the global flag set, test() will advance the
>   lastIndex of the regex. A subsequent use of test() will start the
>   search at the substring of str specified by lastIndex (exec() will
>   also advance the lastIndex property). It is worth noting that the
>   lastIndex will not reset when testing a different string.

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test